Not able to use another NPM package into my custom NPM package locally in react native
I am trying to build one custom react native package that uses react-native-webview internally. I have added the Webview package to the custom package's dependencies and trying to access this package in the example folder as per the documentation.
When I am running the example project getting the "Webview not found" error and on disabling the webview code the example project is working fine.
I am unsure if it is possible, so please help me in case anything is wrong from my side.
I have published the code here on this repo:- https://github.com/faisalkhan1690/test-package-faisal




